# CodeIgniter login system

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new in CodeIgniter and I tried to create a login system on my website..
i am trying to make a login page in codeigniter

here is my code..

**controller**

```
public function login(){
$this->load->database();
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->model('Login');
 $data = $this->Login->login();
 if(! $data){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $this->load->view('login');
    }else{
        // If user did validate, 
        // Send them to members area
       redirect('Home/index');
    }    

 }
```

**View**

```
  <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="<?php echo 
  site_url('Home/login');?>">
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-
  xs-12">
                                <div class="field-label">User Name *</div>
                                <input type="text" name="username" 
  placeholder="User Name" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-
  xs-12">
                                <div class="field-label">Password *</div>
                                <input type="password" name="pass" 
  placeholder="Password" required>
                             </div>


                            <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-
  xs-12 text-right">
                                <button class="normal-btn theme-btn" 
  type="submit" name="submit-form">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
```

**model**

```
 class Login extends CI_Model{
 function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
 }

 public function login(){
    // grab user input
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('pass'));

    // Prep the query
    $this->db->where('doc_email', $username);
    $this->db->where('pass', $password);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('doctors');
    // Let's check if there are any results
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        // If there is a user, then create session data
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
                'doc_id' => $row->doc_id,                    
                'doc_email' => $row->doc_email
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    // If the previous process did not validate
    // then return false.
    return false;
}
}
```

nothing happened when i enter right username and password

Comment: Hi! What do you expect us to do? What is your specific question? Please tell us where exactly your problem is and how you tried to solve it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, change this:

```
if($query->num_rows == 1)
```

into this:

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1)
```

You use property and method interchangeably..

Comment: i want to send a verification link  to registered users mail id.. can you suggest me

Comment: You're welcome. It would be even more useful for others if you could accept the answer..

Comment: can you suggest me how user get verification link to his mail id

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php 
 class Login extends CI_Model{
 function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
 }

 public function login(){
    // grab user input
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('pass'));

    // Prep the query
    $this->db->where('doc_email', $username);
    $this->db->where('pass', $password);

    // Run the query
    $data = $this->db->get('doctors')->row();
    //my changes is here..
    if (count($data) > 0) {
        $sdata = array(
                'doc_id' => $data->doc_id,                    
                'doc_email' => $data->doc_email
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```